# word wrap acting differently on chrome than other browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a website that contains a list of news headlines. In most browsers, these links wrap correctly, but in Google Chrome, the text extends beyond it's container. Examples of Firefox and Chrome below...

[Firefox http://www.mattconnolly.com/Examples/news-firefox.jpg](http://www.mattconnolly.com/Examples/news-firefox.jpg)
[Chrome http://www.mattconnolly.com/Examples/news-chrome.jpg](http://www.mattconnolly.com/Examples/news-chrome.jpg)

The HTML is just a list of ul/li links...

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://www.iiwengr.com/2016/05/23/tranmer-returns-to-iiw-as-surveying-technical-specialist/">TRANMER RETURNS TO IIW AS SURVEYING TECHNICAL SPECIALIST</a>
<span class="post-date">May 23, 2016</span>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.iiwengr.com/2016/05/16/jasper-joins-iiw-as-construction-leader/">JASPER JOINS IIW AS CONSTRUCTION LEADER</a>
<span class="post-date">May 16, 2016</span>
</li>
<li>
<a href="http://www.iiwengr.com/2016/05/11/changing-a-citys-narrative-with-a-streetscape/">CHANGING A CITY’S NARRATIVE</a>
<span class="post-date">May 11, 2016</span>
</li>
</ul>
```

Here's some CSS that is being applied...
    ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
    }

```
ul li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dedfe0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 8%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-align: left;
}

ul li a {
    color: black;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 80%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Any advice on how to get consistent results would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the initial post... edited with much more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to the site to find the problem because the culprit in the code wasn't actually included in the question.

But if you remove this bit:

```
#home-widget-three #secondary .widget ul li a:after {
    content:"\a";
    white-space: pre;
}
```

From line 331 in style.css it looks good in Chrome too. Not sure what that piece of code is supposed to do?

Also, instead of giving both the `li a` and `li span` a width of <100%, just give the `li` a padding on the right side too. Cleaner and more maintainable imo.

Comment: Thanks powerbouy, that was the culprit. I honestly can't remember what that element was for in the first place. I think it was an attempt to add a line break after the link, but that was unnessessary.

Answer (score -1):

Add `display: inline-block` and `word-break: break-word;` in your a tag:

```
ul li a {
   display: inline-block;
   word-break: break-word;
}
```

Comment: He already has `word-wrap: break-word`. Changing from `display: block` to `inline-block` changes nothing on the site in question.